# newbie Elasticsearch question - importing tab delimited files without logstash

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to import such a file into Elasticsearch without using logstash? My log files are fairly straightforward, 6 fields, one of which is a timestamp and the rest are text. Can I also bulk load these files ( maybe like 30 at a time)?

Comment: I believe you need some kind of transformer to make your log data look like json before you load it into ES. `Filebeat` can load the data but not sure how the transformation works

Comment: Please have a look at my answer to a similar question few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240963/elasticsearch-plain-text-file-instead-of-json/56243299#56243299

Comment: ibexit - I asked a similar question on the Elasticsearch forum and received pretty much the same answer about the api wanting to receive the data as json. I don't think Elasticsearch came out and explicitly stated that, but I know that all the examples I saw online were with json. That should have been the clue right there. Thank you for your response.